# How to use RxJS in custom class?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's assume I have following class:

```
class XHRUpload {
    constructor() {
        // Some AJAX code here and listening on progress event,
        // and then pass the progress info out of this class.
    }
}
```

Also I have an Observable object:

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
    obs.next(/* progress info here */)
})
```

But how should I use this observable object in the class to be able to use it outside the class?

The only thing what can I do right now is this:

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
    new XHRUpload(obs)

    // Then in the class...
    obs.next(/* progress info here */)
})

// And then...
observable.subscribe({
    next: value => {/* Progress data... */},
    error: err => {/* Something bad has happened! */},
    complete: () => {/* Transfer has been completed! */}
})
```

But it seems like a bad practice, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out!

```
const observable = new Rx.Subject()

observable.subscribe({
    next: value => {/* Progress data... */},
    error: err => {/* Something bad has happened! */},
    complete: () => {/* Transfer has been completed! */}
})

const obj = new XHRUpload(observable)
```

And class will be:

```
class XHRUpload {
    constructor(observable) {
        // Some great code here...

        observable.next(/* some progress data */)
    }
}
```